# 2.8 Cursor Orientation

Tags: 3d-cursor, transform-orientation

Since the interface to 2.8 is now frozen, I think this is a fair question?

In previous demonstrations and [answers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/126630/35559) concerning the behavior of the cursor in Blender 2.8 I have seen the option (by dragging with the 'Cursor' tool selected,) to set the location and orientation of the 3D Cursor to the face beneath it in  the 3D view, independently of the snapping system.

I've also seen the creation of new objects aligned to the orientation of the 3D cursor, rather than the world, or the view. Try as I might, I can't find a way to reproduce this behavior in my fairly recent build of 2.8.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most straight forward and "useful" thing that I managed to find online is as follows:

- Select the 3D Cursor tool
- Open the properties tab (N), check "surface select" and select "Geometry"

[image]

- Click on a face: the cursor will stick to that face and orient itself so it's normal to the face

[image]

- Go to edit mode and select the "Add Box" tool

[image]

- Click and drag
- Poof you've now created a box that is normal to the face you selected

[image]

Warning: 3DCursor Tool in Edit mode and object mode are independant so if you click again on the cube in edit mode it will reposition itself based on the configuration of the edit mode's 3D Cursor tool

That's something I found in a Youtube video from "Blender Developers" from a year ago so maybe you can do more things with it now or maybe in the future I don't know.

Comment: Phew.Thank you. I _was_ missing something obvious. But I spent half a morning looking for it. I'll assume some others might find it as difficult as I did to find it, and so the 'silly' question may not be so silly :/.. This winds up being the faster replacement for temporary Custom Transforms I guessed must be there, somewhere.