# Is there a quick way to orient the 3D cursor to geometry in Edit Mode?

Tags: 3d-cursor

Blender 2.8 introduced the nice feature that the 3D cursor can be automatically aligned to geometry when clicking on a surface in Object Mode, if 3D Cursor > Active Tool "Surface Project" and "Orientation: Geometry" is activated.

[image: Screenshot: Cursor Tools]

To place the 3D cursor aligned to the surface normals in the center of a surface I currently need two steps: I first place the cursor in Object Mode somewhere on the surface of interest, then switch to Edit Mode, select the surface and move the cursor with Shift-S "(2) Cursor to Selected" in the center of the surface.

Is there a way to place the 3D cursor aligned a face normal in Edit Mode without leaving Edit Mode?

Although 3D cursors in Object Mode and Edit Mode are independent, as stated [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141168/2-8-cursor-orientation), fortunately, the 3D cursor does not change its rotation, when switching from Object Mode to Edit Mode.

Comment: I wish. I really think Shift-S should respect the settings in the Cursor Tool. IMO, it badly needs fixing.It would speed things up a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs i found that booleans make 3d cursor works properly. I really don't know how but here's the example. Sorry for my english by the way https://youtu.be/-4E6Xx9nayc

Answer (score 0):

I found that using the tool version (<kbd>T</kbd> panel) of the 3D cursor instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>` works if you set the orientation to Geometry. I'm not sure if I'm using standard keybinds, but for me it's <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Works like a charm. To move along those new axis you just set the *Transform Orientation* to *Cursor* and you're good to go.